# How to quickly delete millions of files

Tags: c++, boost

We use BOOST1.63 `boost::filesystem::remove_all(dir_to_remove)` to remove a folder that has millions of files (each file has size of 1MB). The folder "dir_to_remove" has sub-folders, and each sub-folder has no more than 1000 files. It takes more than 10-min to delete all files. We use CentOS6.5.

After checking the operations.cpp, we realized BOOST actually uses Linux `rmdir` and `unlink` commands:

```
#   define BOOST_REMOVE_DIRECTORY(P)(::rmdir(P)== 0)
#   define BOOST_DELETE_FILE(P)(::unlink(P)== 0)
```

This [article](https://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux) listed several ways to delete files more efficiently on Linux. And it recommended to use `rsync`.

How can we delete millions of files quickly with C++?

Comment: You may want to use an OS API since the OS is optimized for file handling.

Comment: Are all the files in a single folder or all of them scattered across the file system?

Comment: Look at the source code for `rm` for the `-rf` option, and see how that was implemented (albeit in C, probably).

Comment: Unlink is the trivial, obvious way to implement removal of a list of files. I'm guessing that the optimal solution is far from trivial. How about checking out how rsync does its magic? It's open source.

Comment: What's wrong with using system commands?  I assume the OS folks have optimized those.

Comment: @LoganPaul The files are not in a single folder. There are sub-folders. Each sub-folder has no more than 1000 files.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here, and assume this is going to be used to create malware, or a virus. Both of which are against the terms of use of this site.

Comment: @Krythic you never know till you really know :)

Comment: @Krythic Unfortunately, your assumption is wrong in my case.

Comment: @Matt: "System commands" - do you mean the shell? Because that's a traditional Unix design flaw. It's trying to be both a primitive User Interface as well as an API. This mixing of responsibilities is not a good idea, and the actual implementation is further constrained by the desire for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @werk I checked out rsync source. It does in fact call `unlink`. Have you tested whether `rsync` is faster than your program? Perhaps your filesystem is just slow. BTRFS for example is notoriously slow at deleting files.

Comment: @werk "Unfortunately"? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, `std::filesystem::directory_iterator` is pretty borked. I'm looking to replace that facility entirely in upcoming [P1031 Low level file i/o](https://wg21link.to/P1031) (note won't be live on WG21 until June 2018) with something which scales well to input, so we're on it.

In the meantime, I'd suggest that you use https://ned14.github.io/afio/ which is the reference implementation for P1031, specifically [`directory_handle::enumerate()`](https://ned14.github.io/afio/classafio__v2__xxx_1_1directory__handle.html#ac4b90958be1b1b620a6768de52407935). This library handles directories with millions, even tens of millions, of files with ease. Once you have your list of entries to delete, you need to follow a B+-tree friendly deletion pattern i.e. sort them into either alphabetical or inode order, then do one of:

1. Unlink from the first entry going forwards.
2. Unlink from the last entry going backwards.
3. Unlink from the first entry, then the last entry, moving towards the centre.

I'd benchmark all six approaches for your particular filing system, and choose whichever is the fastest. Some use B+ trees based on inode number, some based on leafname, it varies. But basically you want to avoid excessive tree rebalancing, and avoid deep O(log N) lookups of the leafname, hence the ordered unlinks.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get free a required location, the fastest way to do it is moving (or renaming) a directory to another location on the same partition. Then your program can continue work with a required location and remove a previously moved directory recursively in another thread (in background). This thread can even work with less priority, so removing a specific directory would look like an instant filesystem operation.

Comment: This is what we did in production. However, when designing large backup facilities, we made it possible to simply drop filesystems instead of wiping individual files.

Answer (score 1):

The article you link to talks about the shell perspective. That is critically important: the shell starts programs for many tasks. And while starting a program is very cheap, it can be expensive when you need to start a million programs. That's why `rsync` is so effective; a single invocation can do all the work.

The same already applies to your program. You start your program once; the cost is simply all the syscalls you're making.

I checked the syscall list; there's no syscall that allows you to do a bulk removal with one syscall so you're limited to one syscall per file to remove.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the storage architecture, you can get a speed-up by deleting files in parallel. So, split the work among `std::thread`s, or if you wanna try really quick, use an OpenMP pragma.

This is how I manage my ~ 200 TB storage boxes.

Note, that is possible to have a slight race condition, if any of the files link to each other, but as long as you handle the error it should be fine.